# Local in scheme

Tags: scheme, local, racket

I am just making up random programs and looking if I can use `local`. Is there a way I can use `local` for this? -

```
(define (filt n)
  (filter number? n))

(define (mapn n)
 (map add1 (filt n)))

(define (mapl n)
  (map list (mapn n)))

    (check-expect (mapl(list 1 2 false "true" "b" 'b true 4 9)) (list (list 2) (list 3) (list 5) (list 10)))
```

The first program makes sure the output are only numbers. The second one adds 1 to each number, and the third program creates a list of each individual element inside the list.

I tried but I get no answer and end up with a user break.

```
(define (mapit n)
  (local [(define (filt l)
          (filter number? l))]
    (local [(define (mapn b)
             (map add1 b))]
      (mapit (map list n)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `let`.

```
(let ( (name value)
       (othername othervalue))
  expression-using-name)
```

So

```
(define (map-it n)
  (let ((filt (lambda (l)
                 (filter number? l)))
        (mpan (lambda (b)
                 (map add1 b))))
     (mapit map list n)))
```

But what are you trying to accomplish here? You're not actually using `mapn` or `filt` anywhere.

I think you can just use

```
(define (mapl n)
  (define (filt n)
    (filter number? n))

  (define (mapn n)
   (map add1 (filt n)))

  (map list (mapn n)))
```

Since scheme allows nested definitions.